# Specify dependency versions when using openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm currently trying to use **openapi-generator-maven-plugin** on some api.yaml.

I'm doing that internally in my company, and I have encountered an issue I'm not sure how to solve:
One of the dependency it produces is org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client version 1.0.2, but I'm allowed to use 1.0.0 version only in my company.

Is there a way to specify versions for specific for dependencies when using openapi-generator so it will create dependencies with specify version so we will not later change the version manually?

Thanks!!!

Comment: try adding exclusion for ```org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client ``` in the plugin and in dependencies add the dependency with the required version.

Comment: I tried this before writing this post, but it didn't work.

Comment: @GauravkumarSingh Apache Oltu has been retired. Is there a way to control what `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` will use for OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

You can use customized templates (-t if you're using CLI) to meet your requirements.

If you need further help from the OpenAPI Generator community, please open a ticket via http://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new

Comment: Hi William, Apache Oltu was [retired in 2018](https://attic.apache.org/projects/oltu.html). Is there a way to configure `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` to use a different OAuth2 implementation? I should add I'm using the default HTTP client `okhttp-gson`.

Comment: I think the `jersey2` library supports a different Oauth2 implementation. Please give it a try.